# Problemas conexión a Mongodb comando mongod

Tags: javascript, mongodb, windows10

Hola instalé **Mongo** **3.4** desde el ayudante para **window 10**, pero tengo algunos problemas para hacerlo correr, ya he configurado la ruta , pero no me deja arrancarlo ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi error  por si lo quieren ver más a detalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuve un problema similar. 
Crea la carpeta que te indica ahí:

```
C:\data\db
```

Comment: ty good wise man